# How to align bootstrap navigation bar text with image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstraps navigation bar  and I inserted an image to the navbar brand yet because of the size it messes up the alignment. I want the text that goes along with it to line up with the middle of it like it is, yet I can't figure out how to get the other button text to line up with it as well.

This is what it looks like [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoiNL.png)

```
<a class ="navbar-brand" id="home" href="/">
                    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/901496285759168554/1045812932535128084/jeffersonlogo.webp" width="40" height="60" class="d-inline-block align-middle" alt="">
                      Jefferson Robotics</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="water" href="/underwater">Underwater</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="sky" href="/aerial">Aerial</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="earth" href="/land">Land</a>
```

I tried using alignments on the nav-items but it doesn't change anything no matter what I do, this is my first time using bootstrap and I have limited html knowledge so I am quite lost on what to do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `d-flex align-items-center` classes from bootstrap on both parent element to all the `<a>` tags and also on the `navbar-brand` `<a>` tag like below. This will center the elements vertically.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" id="home" href="/">
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/901496285759168554/1045812932535128084/jeffersonlogo.webp" width="40" height="60" class="d-inline-block align-middle" alt=""> Jefferson Robotics</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="water" href="/underwater">Underwater</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="sky" href="/aerial">Aerial</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="earth" href="/land">Land</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong with your implementation. I tried wrapping your code snippet with the nav container as mentioned in [bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) and it looks fine:

```css
a.nav-item {
  color: white;
}

a.nav-item:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" id="home" href="/">
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/901496285759168554/1045812932535128084/jeffersonlogo.webp" width="40" height="60" class="d-inline-block align-middle" alt=""> Jefferson Robotics</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="water" href="/underwater">Underwater</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="sky" href="/aerial">Aerial</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="earth" href="/land">Land</a>
</nav>
```

maybe you were just missing that wrapper? or maybe you didn't include the styling for bootstrap in your static styles in you HTML file?